# how to avoid face detection on photos facerecognizer/opencv

Tags: opencv

So, i'm running some code using facerecognizer, and it works pretty well. It even detects faces on photographs, which is awesome. But what if i would not want this. Obviously someone could easily pretend to be me by using a photograph of me in front of their face.

Is their a way, or maybe by adjusting the parameters in detectMultiscale, to not do this ? I realize this might be pretty hard.

Comment: you can add some extra checks like showing some random numbers on the screen on random coordinates. you can check his eye movements etc.

Comment: eye movement is a good idea. Could you elaborate on displaying random numbers on the screen? I'm not sure how to interpret that.